# Android Studio-- conditionally compile a class in or not?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Is it possible to tell Android Studio to ignore a single class file completely when compiling?  I have several utility classes, all in one folder, that get compiled into each project.  One of the classes is non-compliant with a Google Family policy, so I want to skip that one when I compile, but ONLY for that particular app.

In C++ this would be very easy to do with a simple define.  Is there a way to do it with Java?  Again, I want to ignore the whole file completely, not just parts of it.

Comment: I think the Android way of doing this is with Proguard...

Comment: Not sure if this possible if the class is in the same module but I guess this could be done if the problematic class is added into a new module. Then use conditional implementation like `debugImplementation` or `releaseImplenentation`, etc. The thing is you'll have to use those classes with names and check if they are available like `Class.forName()` in a try catch. I'd also suggest using a base interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, s I'm answering this just so it exists out there with  an answer.

No, there appears to be no way to do this in Android Studio.  The proguard method will keep the class file from being generated, but it will still try to compile the java, thus causing compile errors if you have something missing that the class expects to be there.

I "solved" this problem by just commenting out the entire java file for the compile for the specific app in question.  It just has to be commented and uncommented for different compiles.  No streamlined solution exists as of June, 2023.